# How to transfer the string to a dict with pysparkSQL

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In pysparkSQL, I have a DataFrame called `bmd2` like this:

```
DataFrame[genres: string, id: int, tagline: string, title: string, vote_average: double, vote_count: int]
```

And the data `bmd2['genres']` goes like this:

```
bmd2.select('genres').show():
```

```
+--------------------+
|              genres|
+--------------------+
|[{'id': 16, 'name...|
|[{'id': 12, 'name...|
|[{'id': 10749, 'n...|
|[{'id': 35, 'name...|
|[{'id': 35, 'name...|
|[{'id': 28, 'name...|
|[{'id': 35, 'name...|
|[{'id': 28, 'name...|
|[{'id': 28, 'name...|
|[{'id': 12, 'name...|
|[{'id': 35, 'name...|
|[{'id': 35, 'name...|
|[{'id': 10751, 'n...|
|[{'id': 36, 'name...|
|[{'id': 28, 'name...|
|[{'id': 18, 'name...|
|[{'id': 18, 'name...|
|[{'id': 80, 'name...|
|[{'id': 80, 'name...|
|[{'id': 28, 'name...|
+--------------------+
only showing top 20 rows
```

The type of data in column 'genres' are string, but they could be transfer to a list of dicts with 'eval function' in python. So how should I apply the eval() here to transfer the string here to list in every row?I tried many ways:

> 1. bmd2.select('genres'.astype('list')):AttributeError: 'str' object
>      has no attribute 'astype'
> 2. bmd2.select(eval('genres')):NameError: name 'genres' is not defined
> 3. bmd2.withColumn('genres',eval('genres')):NameError: name 'genres'
>      is not defined

Comment: where do you want to store the list of dictionaries?

Comment: still in 'genres' or a new column, both will be OK

Comment: can we see the dataframe without truncation? It would be helpful if you provide sample output too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my question by using UDF, which is User-defined function.

First,import it:

`from pyspark.sql.functions import udf`

Then, define your UDF, just like an anonymous function:

`getdirector = udf(lambda x:[i['name'] for i in x if i['job'] == 'Director'],StringType())`

You should assign the type of return value here, so you will get a return value with your expected type. Then you can call this UDF in your code like other functions.

`cres2 = cres1.select('id',getcharacter('cast').alias('cast'),getdirector('crew').alias('crew'))`

In this problem, I can modify the UDF to get any type I need.

Answer (score 1):

I'm writing this as an answer as I can't find the comment option. I would suggest you take a look at from_json from the pyspark.sql.functions. For example, this is how you would use it:

```
# given a row that looks like:

+----------genres-------------+
| [{ id:1, name:"hiphop"}]    |
+-----------------------------+

# define a schema
schema = ArrayType(StructType().add("id", IntegerType())\
                              .add("name", StringType()))

# transform
new_df = df.select(from_json("genres", schema).alias("genres_dict"))

# display
new_df.printSchema()
new_df.show()
```

There is one more method to achieve this using a function called regexp_extract. But the above is my personal preference. Also if you want to switch back to the original string you can use to_json function. Hope this helps.